# MacBook Air M1 connected to Dell U2723QE: Sound output yes, sound input no

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I bought the Dell U2723QE monitor and connected through USB-C (not HDMI or DP) to MacBook Air M1, while I can still get the sound output to M1 while playing a video for example, there is no input sound when I go to Sound in Settings.

So I can't talk via Whatsapp, I can hear them but them not. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The U2723QE does not support a microphone input via the audio jack, and it does not have a built-in microphone. You'll need to use a USB microphone or plug another microphone directly into your MacBook.

[image]

Comment: I see, so I can plug a USB headphones with a microphone to the screen and it should work?

Comment: Or better I can buy a Jack 3.5 to USB C adapter for my current headphones and that should fix it?

Comment: Yes, both of those solutions should work (assuming you get a 3.5mm adapter that has a microphone inpput.)